# I can not install CocoaPods and any package from "Add package dependency"

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I am using a Mac M1 Pro. I am new to iOS development.
When I  added CocoaPods like Lottie and Kingfisher they were not getting added and I could not add a package from the form  "Add package dependency". I can not add any third-party package.

[image: Cocoapod installation issue]

[image: SPM installation issue]

Comment: CocoaPods and Swift Package Manager are typically not interoperable. Choose one  package manager.